# Calling non-const member function from const object without using this, why is it an error?

Tags: c++, gcc

Running the code below in g++ will result the following error:

> error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

```
struct A{
    void f(){};
};

int main(){
    const A a;
    a.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Where do we use `this`?

fpermissive implies that the code is non-conformant.
Where does the standard states that this is an error?

Comment: You use `this` every time you call a class method.

Comment: If you want a solution qualify `f` as `const` -> `void f() const {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard covers `this` in [[class.this]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.this). In particular, see example 2, where it says (in part):

> The call `y.g()` is ill-formed because `y` is `const` and `s​::​g()` is a non-const member function.

When applied to your code, the equivalent statement is:

> The call `a.f()` is ill-formed because `a` is `const` and `A​::f()` is a non-const member function.

To be clearer: `A::f()` is non-const because it lacks a `const` qualification; whether or not `f()` would be a legal const function (if the `const` qualification was added) is not relevant.

Perhaps what you are really interested in, though, is the first part of [class.this], where it states that the keyword `this` has a meaning in every non-static member function, regardless of whether or not `this` is ever used in that function.